# How to calculate matrix entries efficently using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array `myBasis` of sparse matricies `B_1`,...,`B_n`.

I want to evaluate with Matlab the matrix `Q(i,j) = trace (B^T_i * B_j)`.

Therefore, I wrote the following code:

```
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        B=myBasis{i};        
        C=myBasis{j};   
        Q(i,j)=trace(B'*C);
    end
end
```

Which takes already 68 seconds when `n=1226` and `B_i` has 50 rows, and 50 colums.

Is there any chance to speed this up? Usually I exclude for-loops from my matlab code in a c++ file - but I have no experience how to handle a sparse cell array in C++.

Comment: You could try a parfor and run the loops in parallel. http://www.mathworks.se/help/distcomp/parfor.html

Comment: Actually, this might be a nice exercise to implement in C++.

Comment: @patrik  Actually I want to run my script on 12800000000 matricies where each matrix has 400 rows, 400 columns, and at most 405 entries. Therefore I think I should use sparse matricies.

Comment: Even storing 12 800 000 000 8 byte numbers will require 95 TB of storage so that is nonsense in my opinion

Comment: @patrik I just noticed that I made a calculation error instead of 12800000000 it are only 80000. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Adam I see, then it makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As noted by [Inox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24934987/1714410) `Q` is symmetric and therefore you only need to explicitly compute half the entries.
2. Computing `trace( B.'*C )` is equivalent to `B(:).'*C(:)`:
   `trace(B.'*C)` = `sum_i [B.'*C]_ii` = `sum_i sum_j B_ij * C_ij`
   which is the sum of element-wise products and therefore equivalent to `B(:).'*C(:)`.
   When explicitly computing `trace( B.'*C )` you are actually pre-computing *all* k-by-k entries of `B.'*C` only to use the diagonal later on. AFAIK, Matlab does not optimize its calculation to save it from computing all the entries.

Here's a way

```
for ii = 1:n
    B = myBasis{ii};  
    for jj = ii:n
        C = myBasis{jj};
        t = full( B(:).'*C(:) ); % equivalent to trace(B'*C)!
        Q(ii,jj) = t;
        Q(jj,ii) = t;
    end
end
```

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

PPS,
You should notice that [`'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) operator in Matlab is **not** matrix transpose, but [hermitian conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose), for actual transpose you need to use [`.'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html). In most cases complex numbers are not involved and there is no difference between the two operators, but once complex data is introduced, confusing between the two operators makes debugging quite a mess...

Comment: You must use `full(t)` to make it equal to the matlab implementation of trace. `trace` converts `t` to a full matrix again. This is probably a time thief as well. @Adam are you sure sparse matrices are needed here? 1226*50*50 is 3 million elements. For double it means a little less than 30Mb. That is not so bad.

Comment: Yes, but `myBasis` is only a 1D array, temporary storing the other elements will not do a serious damage. So I think it is 1226*50*50. Correct me if I miss something.

Comment: @patrik I take it back. thanks for the `full` comment. you might comment the question directly about converting it all to full.

Comment: @Shai are you sure this works for sparse matricies as well? I dont understand why I need the full command. Sry - I get it now.

Comment: @Adam you only `full` the result - which is a scalar. a representation thing. you can try without it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a couple of thoughts

1) Basic stuff: A'*B = (B'*A)' and trace(A) = trace(A'). Well, only this trick cut your calculations by almost 50%. Your Q(i,j) matrix is symmetric, and you only need to calculate n(n+1)/2 terms (and not n²)

2) To calculate the trace you don't need to calculate every term of B'*C, just the diagonal. Nevertheless, I don't know if it's easy to create a script in Matlab that is actually faster then just calculating B'*C (MatLab is pretty fast with matrix operations).

But I would definitely implement (1)